# PostgreSql 8.4 extension for JSON

Tags: postgresql

I need to port a function that uses `row_to_json` and `json_agg` from PostgreSql 9.5 to 8.4 and I wonder if is there an extension for 8.4 to allow converting queries/table results to JSON in a similar way as `row_to_json` and `json_agg` do.

Comment: I think it will be easier to migrate your (unsupported) Postgres 8.4 installation to a modern, supported version.

Comment: Yes, that was the first option I thought, but as the db is huge and the server doesn't have the needed free space to migrate that's not an option.

Comment: You can migrate using `pg_upgrade` using the `--link` option (although I am not 100% if this is supported with such an ancient version). Or you could use `pg_dump` from a different computer that has enough space. Or you could simply attach an external USB drive for the duration of the migration. Where do you store the backups btw?

Comment: I think 8.4 is already supported by pg_upgrade. But then again, you really should have a backup before doing the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks to all, as it's practically impossible to do the upgrade right now, I'll write the conversion to JSON using an external program.